# Firebase Storage - Upload Image with React Native, Error loading Preview

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

This is the code which I use to upload images to firebase storage

```
const filename = image.substring(image.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.replace('file://', '') : image
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};
const task = firebase.storage().ref().put(uploadUri, metadata)
try {
 await task
} catch(err) {
 console.log(err)
}
```

But when I check the firebase console it shows, error loading preview, and the file size is 9B for a image. Is there something Im missing.
[image: [Firebase Console Pic]]

Im using Expo managed, expo-image-picker to select images.

Comment: Do you have any issue in picking up iamges from `expo-image-picker`. My app is restarting as soon as I pick an image.

Comment: No, expo-image-picker works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, I had to create a blob and then upload the blob to firebase

```
    const filename = image.substring(image.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function() {
        reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
      };
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.open("GET", image, true);
      xhr.send(null);
    });
    const ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child(filename);
      
    const task = ref.put(blob, { contentType: 'image/jpeg' });

    task.on('state_changed', 
      (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.totalBytes)
      }, 
      (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }, 
      () => {
        task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
          console.log(downloadURL);
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this

```
const filename = image.substring(image.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? image.replace('file://', '') : image

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", {
   name: filename,
   type: 'image/jpeg',
   uri: uploadUri
})

var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

const task = firebase.storage().ref().put(formData, metadata)
try {
 await task
} catch(err) {
 console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, still error loading preview and the file size is 9B

Answer (score 0):

my code is working perfect by adding file type basically default file type is mime that's why it didn't show on firebase and by resolving promise I send reference and URL URL to show image and if I want to delete image so I by using this reference I delete this image.

```
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

import { storage } from "src/firebase";

function slugify(str) {
  if (typeof str !== "string") return str;
  return str
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, "_") // Replace spaces with hyphens
    .replace(/--+/g, "_"); // Replace consecutive hyphens with a single hyphen
}
export const uploadFileAndGetDownloadURL = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create the file metadata
    const metadata = {
      contentType: file.file.type,
    };
    let reference = `images/${file.file.lastModified}_${slugify(
      file.file.name
    )}`;
    // Create a reference to the storage location
    const storageRef = ref(storage, reference);

    // Upload file and metadata to the storage location
    const uploadTask = uploadBytes(storageRef, file.file, metadata);

    uploadTask.then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(storageRef)
        .then((url) => {
          resolve({ url, reference });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error.message);
        });
    });
  });
};
uploadFileAndGetDownloadURL({file:event.target.file[0], url:URL.createObjectURL(event.target.file[0])})
```

I'm using the react.js with firebase and make sure upload file

Comment: Provide some comments to indicate how your code solves the problem rather than just writing a wall of code.